# Pandas scatterplot coming out wonky for one dataframe and perfectly for another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a basic scatterplot with pandas. I have two dataframes with identical structures, column numbers, headers etc. The only difference is that on DF has a couple of dozen rows, and the other has several thousand rows. When I create a scattplot for the first DF I get this, exactly what I want:

[image]

But when I enter the same commands for the second, larger dataframe, it comes out wonky (for lack of a better term), specifically the y-axis. It is also not showing all of the data points:

[image]

I've messed around with the headings, limits, etc., and I can't get the second scatterplot to work. Any ideas? I'm wondering if there's some property of the second dataframe that I cannot figure out that's throwing it off...

Comment: Can you create two sample dataframes that exhibit this behavior and post the code here so we can recreate it?

Comment: Interesting. Can you try with `sns` and see if this replicates?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Okay, so in an attempt to prepare sample dataframes for commentor 1 above, I realized that the problem datafram was being read from a CSV file, and the dataframe that was working fine was being loaded from an xlsx file. I copied and pasted the contents of the csv file into a new xlsx files, loaded it as a new dataframe, and tried the scatterplot on that dataframe instead. It now works perfectly. I'm pretty new to pandas so I have no idea why this might be--once the contents of a sheet are loaded as a dataframe, I assumed any differences due to the file type were eliminated?